# function in C++: define it before use it

Tags: c++, method-resolution-order

In C/C++, the caller function can call the callee function if and only if the callee function is visible to the caller, which means the callee's definition should be done before where it's used, otherwise use forward-declaration.

Here is my problem,

```
class A
{
    public:
        void foo()
        {
            bar();
        }

        void bar()
        {
            //...
        }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.foo();
}
```

The above code will work just fine. But `foo` calls `bar` and I didn't put `bar`'s definition before `foo` or forward-declare `bar`, how could the call to `bar` in `foo` work? How could the compiler find `bar`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The language says that the scope of a member function declaration is the whole class (loosely), so this is fine.

What actually happens is that the compiler waits until the end of the class definition (indeed, the end of the outermost enclosing class definition) before attempting to analyse the bodies of the inline functions.

So it only looks at the call to `bar` at the end of the class, by which time it has seen its declaration and all is well.

Comment: If I move function's definition out of the body of the class, then the function declaration in class body will act as forward-decl, right?

Comment: Yes. And if you move them both out you can define them in any order.

Answer (score 3):

The body of a member function defined inside the definition of a class is a special case:  for the purpose of name lookup it is as if the member function was defined immediately after the end of the class definition.

This is why a member function can refer in its definition to other members of the class of which it is a member, regardless where in the class definition it is defined.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it is called [`Forward reference`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)

> > The term **forward reference** is sometimes used as a synonym of **forward declaration**. However, more often it is taken to refer to the actual use of an entity before any declaration; that is, the first reference to second in the code above is a forward reference. Thus, we may say that because forward declarations are mandatory in Pascal, forward references are prohibited.
> >
> > Permitting forward references can greatly increase the complexity and memory requirements of a compiler, and generally prevents the compiler from being implemented in one pass.

Comment: According to your answer, I read that, `forward-reference` is deprecated in C++?

Comment: **forward reference** is a new feature of `C++` compared to `C`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a different deal when you are talking about definitions within a class (as opposed to the global scope). I believe this is achieved by the compiler passing over the class for definitions first, *then* looking at the actual implementations of all the methods. To sum up, you do not need to worry about any sort of forward declaration/reference in this case.

Comment: You will still hit trouble if you try to use a type that is a class member before it is defined.